# Required REGEX for a String

Tags: regular-expressions

I am trying to find a solution to validate below string in APEX, is there any regex that can be used ?

SDI001 AND SDI002 --> This is valid

(SDI001 AND SDI002) --> This is valid

SDI001 OR SDI002 --> This is valid

(SDI001 OR SDI002) --> This is valid

SDI001   AND   SDI002 --> This is not valid (multiple spaces    before and after AND)

Also String is valid with any 'AND' or 'OR' condition (with multiple conditions as well)

Comment: There is (sounds like you are basically trying to detect multiple spaces), but why does multiple spaces matter? If it does matter, why not use `String.replaceAll()` (if you care about this somewhere in Apex)?

Comment: If nested, parenthesized clauses are also valid, you really need a parser not a regex

Answer (score 2):

A regex is almost certainly the wrong solution here. You appear to be trying to validate Boolean filter logic, which allows grouping and nesting of clauses, like

```
(SDI001 AND SDI002) OR SDI003
```

Managing grouping and operator precedence order, while it can in *some* circumstances be done with very complex regular expressions, really demands a parser rather than a regex. (Since you're ultimately going to be parsing the logic anyway, you likely already have to write this code, and it wouldn't be a good solution to *also* use a regex since its behavior may be different).

Once you do go to the extent of parsing this logic properly, extra whitespace should be irrelevant and ignored by the parser.